# Why is double-checked locking broken in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, anti-patterns

**This question relates to behaviour of old Java versions and old implementations of the double checked locking algorithm**

Newer implementations [use `volatile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-double-checked-locking) and rely on slightly changed `volatile` semantics, so they are **not** broken.

---

It's stated that fields assignment is always atomic except for fields of long or double.

But, when I read an explaination of why double-check locking is broken, it's said that the problem is in assignment operation:

```
// Broken multithreaded version
// "Double-Checked Locking" idiom
class Foo {
    private Helper helper = null;
    public Helper getHelper() {
        if (helper == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (helper == null) {
                    helper = new Helper();
                }
            }
        }
        return helper;
    }

    // other functions and members...
}
```

> 1. Thread A notices that the value is not initialized, so it obtains the
>      lock and begins to initialize the
>      value.
> 2. Due to the semantics of some programming languages, the code
>      generated by the compiler is allowed
>      to update the shared variable to point
>      to a partially constructed object
>      before A has finished performing the
>      initialization.
> 3. Thread B notices that the shared variable has been initialized (or so
>      it appears), and returns its value.
>      Because thread B believes the value is
>      already initialized, it does not
>      acquire the lock. If B uses the object
>      before all of the initialization done
>      by A is seen by B (either because A
>      has not finished initializing it or
>      because some of the initialized values
>      in the object have not yet percolated
>      to the memory B uses (cache
>      coherence)), the program will likely
>      crash.
>      
>    (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

When is it possible? Is it possible that on 64-bit JVM assignment operation isn't atomic?
If no then whether "double-checked locking" is really broken?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448864/java-double-locking-can-someone-explain-more-simply-why-intuition-wouldnt-wor/12449110?noredirect=1#comment26446551_12449110

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is not atomicity, it's ordering. The JVM is allowed to reorder instructions in order to improve performance, as long as [happens-before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.4.4) is not violated. Therefore, the runtime could theoretically schedule the instruction that updates `helper` before all instructions from the constructor of class `Helper` have executed.

Answer (score 7):

The assignment of the reference is atomic, but the construction is not! So as stated in the explanation, supposing thread B wants to use the singleton before Thread A has fully constructed it, it cannot create a new instance because the reference is not null, so it just returns the partially constructed object.

> If you do not ensure that publishing
>   the shared reference happens before
>   another thread loads that shared
>   reference, then the  write of the
>   reference to the new object can be
>   reordered with the writes to its
>   fields. In that case, another thread
>   could see  an up-to-date value for the
>   object reference but out of date
>   values for some or all of the object's
>   state - a partially constructed
>   object. -- Brian Goetz: Java Concurrency in Practice

Since the initial check for null is not synchronized there is no publication and this reordering is possible.

Comment: is it stated anywhere that java does the assignment first and only then calculates the right part? (It's kind of the `Future` pattern, but I've never seen official statements about its usage by java compiler).

Comment: @Roman: It's not a simple matter of "Java assigns first and only then calculates the right part". That would be an incorrect statement I think. Java allows the low level code to reorder statements in a way that can cause unexpected results when a shared field that isn't `volatile` or `final` is accessed by another thread.

Answer (score 2):

Several assignments may be needed to construct the instance of `Helper` inside the constructor, and the semantics allows that they are reordered with respect to the assignment `helper = new Helper()`.

So the field `helper` may be assigned a reference to an object where not all assignments have taken place, so that it is incompletely initialized.

Comment: what do you mean "several assignments"? I see only 1: `helper = new Helper()`. If it can be constructed "in place" then could you give a link which proves that java realy does so weird things? Thx.

Comment: @Roman: As mentioned in the quotes in your question, the code generated by the compiler is allowed to assign `Helper` to an instance of `Helper` that _has not completed construction_.

Answer (score 2):

Double checked locking in java has a variety of problems:

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: For Java 5+ it works as expected with no problems if you declare the field being initialized as `volatile` (as mentioned in that paper, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Read this article: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-02-2001/jw-0209-double.html
Even if you did not understand all details (like me) just believe that this nice trick does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
/*Then the following should work.
  Remember: getHelper() is usually called many times, it is BAD 
  to call synchronized() every time for such a trivial thing!
*/
class Foo {

private Helper helper = null;
private Boolean isHelperInstantiated;
public Helper getHelper() {
    if (!isHelperInstantiated) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (helper == null) {
                helper = new Helper();
                isHelperInstantiated = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return helper;
}

// other functions and members...
}
```